# How to enable the automatical service restart of Apache IoTDB when restarting the server?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

To guarantee the stability of the database, can Apache IoTDB enable the service to be automatically started when the server is restarted, or does it require other software to manage the service to be automatically started? If supported, how can I set IoTDB service to be automatically restarted?